# Setting property in separate view controller using delegate method from another VC - Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, protocols, auth0, delegation

I am using Auth0 to authenticate users in an app. The `auth0` login is defined in `BaseViewController`. Once authenticated, I need to update info in the `LoginViewController` with details obtained from the authentication.

So I have:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftValidator
import Lock
import Auth0

protocol BaseViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func getName()
}

class BaseViewController {

    weak var delegate: BaseViewControllertDelegate?

    var validator = Validator()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadAuth0LoginPage()
    }

    func loadAuth0LoginPage() {
        Lock
        .classic()

        .withOptions {
          $0.oidcConformant = true
          $0.scope = "openid profile"
        }

        .withStyle {
            $0.logo = LazyImage(name: "*****")
            $0.primaryColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.573, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
            $0.headerColor = UIColor.i6.darkGrey
        }

        .onAuth { credentials in
            self.getUserProfile(credentials: credentials)

        }
        .present(from: self)
    }

    func getUserProfile(credentials: Credentials) {
        guard let accessToken = credentials.accessToken else { return }
        Auth0
            .authentication()
            .userInfo(withAccessToken: accessToken)
            .start { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let profile):
                    self.delegate?.getName()

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And then on the LoginViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftValidator
import Lock

class LoginViewController: BaseViewController, BaseViewControllerDelegate {
    func getName() {
        print("get name")
    }

    var baseVC: BaseViewController

    init() {
        self.baseVC = BaseViewController()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        baseVC.delegate = self
    }
```

So I'm setting the protocol on `BaseViewController` and creating the delegate property. I'm then calling the method once `oAuth` has done its bit. In `LoginViewController` I am adopting the protocol and defining the required method. I believe where I'm going wrong is where I am creating the instance of `BaseViewController` and then assigning the delegate to self but I'm a bit stuck as to where this part needs to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The structure doesn't quite make sense.  You're saying that a `LoginViewController` *is* a `BaseViewController`.  That means it shouldn't need a delegate just to talk to itself.  But you're also creating a separate `BaseViewController` and not really doing anything with it.  Maybe take a step back and describe where this name comes from and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks Phillip - this proves why it's not always good to work late at night! I was way over complicating this as you suggested. I was easily able to access the property from within the BaseViewController... cheers for responding